# Grub doesn't install - corrupted iso?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, iso

I wanted to install Arch Linux on my netbook. I hadn't important files on my hard drive so I've created new partition table (GPT) using GParted from Fedora LiveCD. When I'm running

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I get errors and my new system will not run from GRUB. How can I fix it? Is it a corrupted iso file? I'll add it isn't a problem with hard drive - before Arch, there was Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: Have you installed arch? What errors do you get? How can we help if you don't even give us the error messages? Have you actually installed `grub`?

Answer (score 1):

`grub-mkconfig` must be run once GRUB **is installed**, which is done by running :

```
grub-install /dev/sda # Adapt sda.
```

*Tip* : have a look at `man` pages synopsis for more information :

- http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/grub-install/
- http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/grub-mkconfig/

The Arch Wiki also details the installation process accurately :

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide

You will also find GPT-specific instructions here :

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_.28GPT.29_specific_instructions

Comment: Thanks, but I followed Beginners' Guide and I **have** installed GRUB. `grub-install /dev/sda` doesn't signal any errors. I have also installed `os-prober`.

Comment: Can you run `grub-install` with the `--recheck` option ?

Comment: I actually ran it with `--recheck` option.

Comment: Are you in an Arch chroot when running `grub-mkconfig` ? Is the `/boot` partition/disk space available ? We might need more information...

Comment: Yes, I'm in `arch-chroot`. My boot partition is mounted in `/mnt/boot` in host system. Boot partition - 512 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the iso from last December (year 2013) was corrupted. Grub was corrupted. As Arch is a rolling release distro, most users haven't noticed it. Next iso solved this issue.